# Hibernate @PostLoad never gets invoked

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Looked at many forums but haven't found answer...Simple stuff, method annotated with @PostLoad never gets invoked...added listener via @EntityListeners but problem remains. I'm using SessionFactory based configuration.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The EJB3 `@PostLoad` annotation doesn’t work when using a `SessionFactory` based configuration, the post-load method will never get called.

Either use Hibernate's [Interceptors or events](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html) or an `EntityManager` based configuration.

Comment: The callbacks can absolutely work when using SessionFactory.  You simply have to enable the proper Hibernate event listeners yourself.

Comment: Here's how to enable the event listeners: https://n1njahacks.wordpress.com/2016/10/07/jpa-callbacks-with-hibernates-sessionfactory-and-no-entitymanager/

Answer (score 10):

There is also an alternative to hibernate's interceptors or events approach when using SessionFactory: implementing [Lifecycle](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/classic/Lifecycle.html) interface.

Comment: But beware of this bug: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6043 which also holds for Lifecycle.onLoad (is invoked before collections are initialised - until it was fixed in Hibernate 4.1.8)

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to enable JPA's post op annotations in Hibernate 5.

Hibernate’s `IntegratorServiceImpl` uses the `java.util.ServiceLoader` API, so we can specify an additional list of `org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator` implementations we want the `SessionFactory` to use.

All we need to do is specify a service provider in **`META-INF/services/org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator`**:

```
# This allows us to use JPA-style annotation on entities, such as @PostLoad
our.custom.JpaAnnotationsIntegrator
```

You will also need to ensure that ‘`hibernate-entitymanager`‘ jar of the appropriate version is on your classpath.

**`our.custom.JpaAnnotationsIntegrator`** (taken from `org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.JpaIntegrator`):

```
package our.custom;

import org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor;
import org.hibernate.event.service.spi.EventListenerRegistry;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.EventType;
import org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator;
import org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPostDeleteEventListener;
import org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPostInsertEventListener;
import org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPostLoadEventListener;
import org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPostUpdateEventListener;
import org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackBuilderLegacyImpl;
import org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackRegistryImpl;
import org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.jpa.CallbackBuilder;
import org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.jpa.ListenerFactory;
import org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.jpa.ListenerFactoryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass;
import org.hibernate.service.spi.SessionFactoryServiceRegistry;

/**
 * This integrator allows us to use JPA-style post op annotations on Hibernate entities.
 *

 * This integrator is loaded by <code>org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl</code> from
 * <code>META-INF/services/org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator</code> file.
 *

 * <b>Note</b>: This code is lifted directly from <code>org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.JpaIntegrator</code>
 *
 * @author Val Blant
 */
public class JpaAnnotationsIntegrator implements Integrator {
    private ListenerFactory jpaListenerFactory;
    private CallbackBuilder callbackBuilder;
    private CallbackRegistryImpl callbackRegistry;

    @Override
    public void integrate(Metadata metadata, SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        final EventListenerRegistry eventListenerRegistry = serviceRegistry.getService( EventListenerRegistry.class );

        this.callbackRegistry = new CallbackRegistryImpl();

        // post op listeners
        eventListenerRegistry.prependListeners( EventType.POST_DELETE, new JpaPostDeleteEventListener(callbackRegistry) );
        eventListenerRegistry.prependListeners( EventType.POST_INSERT, new JpaPostInsertEventListener(callbackRegistry) );
        eventListenerRegistry.prependListeners( EventType.POST_LOAD, new JpaPostLoadEventListener(callbackRegistry) );
        eventListenerRegistry.prependListeners( EventType.POST_UPDATE, new JpaPostUpdateEventListener(callbackRegistry) );

        // handle JPA "entity listener classes"...
        final ReflectionManager reflectionManager = ( (MetadataImpl) metadata )
                .getMetadataBuildingOptions()
                .getReflectionManager();

        this.jpaListenerFactory = ListenerFactoryBuilder.buildListenerFactory( sessionFactory.getSessionFactoryOptions() );
        this.callbackBuilder = new CallbackBuilderLegacyImpl( jpaListenerFactory, reflectionManager );
        for ( PersistentClass persistentClass : metadata.getEntityBindings() ) {
            if ( persistentClass.getClassName() == null ) {
                // we can have non java class persisted by hibernate
                continue;
            }
            callbackBuilder.buildCallbacksForEntity( persistentClass.getClassName(), callbackRegistry );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void disintegrate(SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        if ( callbackRegistry != null ) {
            callbackRegistry.release();
        }
        if ( callbackBuilder != null ) {
            callbackBuilder.release();
        }
        if ( jpaListenerFactory != null ) {
            jpaListenerFactory.release();
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've also been struggling to make this work on Hibernate4, using the session factory.

I found the solution quite simple but not documented anywhere using Integrator (Apparently the Hibernate4's way to deal with SessionFactory and listeners).
The *hibernate-entitymanager* project provides an Integrator to add the required listeners to link EJB3's annotations *@PostLoad,* ... to the session factory. Just declare the class *JpaIntegrator* the **SPI** way.

Concretely, just add a file named *org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator* in the **META-INF/services** folder and declare the implementation class in it (*org.hibernate.ejb.event.JpaIntegrator*)

Comment: Nice solution. FYI, as of Hibernate 4.3.5, the content of the file should be "org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.JpaIntegrator".

Comment: This is the solution I went with as well, although I found that it will break flush cascades in Hibernate 5. See my answer below for a fix.

Comment: @Matt i know its a very old question but where should i find this META-INF/Services ? i can only find it in the folder where i downloaded hibernate and after making changes, it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Or enable the Hibernate event listeners that handle JPA callbacks.  That is exactly what HEM does.  How that is done is different between Hibernate 3 and Hibernate 4 (you never mentioned which version you are using); check the documentation for details on (a) the event listeners involved and (b) how to specify custom set of listeners.

Comment: Maybe I'm thick, but I'm having a hard time finding how to do this in the documentation for Hibernate 4.