# Ported from JPA to Hibernate, @PostLoad not working anymore

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, weblogic, hibernate-envers

I have recently ported my application from JPA to Hibernate 4.
But I have kept few functionalities of JPA e.g. **`@PostLoad`**.
My application runs on `Weblogic12` and I have put `JPA2.1` in WL `Classpath`.

I have `@PostLoad` annotation in each of the pojos for a Date field.
I am using Hibernate `Envers` as well.
With `JPA` & `EntityManager` everything was working fine.

But now with Hibernate, when I am setting a property of a Child class, only the Child table is getting updated. (In the `AUDIT` table as well. (`Hibernate Envers`)).
While its parents are not getting updated.

Looks like **`@PostLoad`** is not working properly.

```
ChildConfig childConfig = populateChildConfigObject();
grandParentConfig.getParentConfigList.get(0).setchildConfig(childConfig);
```

So, here if I look into the table, only the `ChildConfig` Table gets updated (Main table as well as AUDIT table).

While, the ParentConfig & ChildConfig are not updated.

@PostLoad is somehow not working for the upper class.

Note:- I have also tried to create a Dummy object for the Parent class, and set it again to the GrandParent class. But this has also not `triggered` the Parent & GrandParent.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2805140/1572269.

Comment: Is there any other workaround ?

Comment: Did you not see Steve's comments?  Just register them manually.  The registration happens automatically when you bootstrap an EntityManager, just not a SessionFactory.