# Add Case Statement in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-annotations

I am creating as API which send the response to Client in `JSON` format.
What I am doing, I have a table In `Mysql` DB in that there is a primary key. Client request Data using that Primary Key as a parameter and I am fetching Data from DB using `hibernate` and sending back to Client as a response.

**My SQL Query:**

```
select * from emp_table Where id = 202
```

In JSON Responce I am sending all the column of the table as show in the above Query. Till here my code is working fine.

But now I am generating a new column using `case statement` as show in the below query:

```
select *, (case when sal > 4.5  then 'Yes' else 'No' end)  as bp_status from emp_table Where id = 202
```

How can I send this new `bp_status` column in the `JSON` response??

I tried with the `@Formula` but not working

```
@Formula(value = "(case when sal > 4.5  then 'Yes' else 'No' end)")
private String bp_status;
```

Answer (score 0):

As `sal` column is in your `emp_table` that your `Employee` entity has the `sal` attribute and your entity looks like

```
@Entity
public class Employee{

    @Column(name = "sal")
    private Double sal;

}
```

Then how about using a transient attribute that you load after loading your entity?

```
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.persistence.PostLoad;

@Entity
public class Employee{

    @Column(name = "sal")
    private Double sal;

    // define here as an attribute so that you can do
    // whatever you want in your JSON process
    @Transient
    private String bpStatus;

    public Employee(){
        // ...

        // initialise an empty value to avoid a NullPointerException
        // when processing your JSON
        this.bpStatus = "";
    }

    // Tell JPA to add additional stuff after loading the entity
    @PostLoad
    public void postLoad(){
        // simplified version: you must ensure that
        // sal is not null and stuff like that
        this.bpStatus = (sal > 4.5) ? "Yes" : "No";
    }

}
```

---

<sub>Be careful when overriding post loading methods: as per my experimentation, you only need the `@Override` annotation and you should not annotation an overridden method as `@PostLoad` as JPA will find two post loading methods, even if the signature is the same.</sub>

Comment: Hi Al1, Thanks I tried the above code, I am getting bpStatus in my `Json` response, But every time I am getting default value of `bpStatus` which is blank not `Yes` or `No`, and my sal column is not null

Comment: `@PostLoad` is called by JPA only: are your entities fetched by an entity manager? At this stage, I usually put a mere `System.out.print...` to ensure that my post loading method is called. Otherwise, a dirty hack is to set the `bpStatus` value before calling your JSON methods but it'll ruin the beauty of the JPA design :(

Comment: Hi AI, I am using a `SessionFactory` based configuration 
`sessionFactory = HibernateUtility.getSessionFactory();
            session_hiber = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session_hiber.beginTransaction();`
is this the issue??

Comment: Honestly, I don't know, I am an EclipseLink and EntityManager user. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2805140/4906586) the  `HibernateUtility` is not JPA-standard so `@PostLoad` is never called. [One solution](https://n1njahacks.wordpress.com/2016/10/07/jpa-callbacks-with-hibernates-sessionfactory-and-no-entitymanager/) is suggested here. It looks like Hibernate has a [`@PostLoad` via the `Lifecycle`'s `onLoad()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/classic/Lifecycle.html#onLoad(org.hibernate.Session,%20java.io.Serializable))

Comment: @ansh did you find out a suitable solution?

Comment: No I did not, I tried to Implement `EntityManager` but its not helping me.