# Why saveOrUpdate in Hibernate 5.2 does not behave as documented

Tags: hibernate

In Hibernate 5.2 `org.hibernate.Session.saveOrUpdate()` does not perform an `update` for detached objects but a `save`.

When using Hibernate 3.6 it works as expected.

These are the files to reproduce the problem:

1. The entity `Person.java`:

   ```
   package model;

   import javax.persistence.*;

   @Entity
   public class Person
   {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue
       private Long id;
       @Column(unique = true)
       private String name;
       private Integer age;

       public void setName(String name)
       {
           this.name = name;
       }

       public void setAge(Integer age)
       {
           this.age = age;
       }
   }
   ```
2. The DAO interface `HibernateTestDao.java`:

   ```
   package model;

   public interface HibernateTestDao
   {
       void test();
   }
   ```
3. and the DAO implementation `HibernateTestDaoImpl.java`:

   ```
   package model;

   import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
   import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

   @Transactional(readOnly = true)
   @Repository
   public class HibernateTestDaoImpl implements HibernateTestDao
   {
       @Autowired
       private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

       @Transactional(readOnly = false)
       @Override
       public void test()
       {
           Person person = new Person();
           person.setName("Joe");
           person.setAge(10);

           Long id = (Long)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(person);

           sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();

           person = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Person.class, id);

           sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().clear();

           person.setAge(11);

           sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(person);
           sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();

           throw new RuntimeException();
       }

   }
   ```
4. The main class `HibernateTest.java`:

   ```
   package test;

   import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

   import model.HibernateTestDao;

   public class HibernateTest
   {
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
           ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/applicationContext.xml");

           HibernateTestDao dao = applicationContext.getBean(HibernateTestDao.class);

           dao.test();;

           applicationContext.close();
       }
   }
   ```
5. The Spring configuration file `applicationContext.xml`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.3.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

       <context:component-scan base-package="model"/>

       <bean id="dataSource"  class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
           <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
           <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatetest" />
           <property name="username" value="hibernatetest" />
           <property name="password" value="hibernatetest" />
       </bean>

       <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
           <property name="packagesToScan">
               <list>
                   <value>model</value>
               </list>
           </property>
           <property name="hibernateProperties">
               <props>
                   <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
                   <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</prop>
                   <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                   <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
                   <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
               </props>
           </property>
           <property name="dataSource">
               <ref bean="dataSource"/>
           </property>
       </bean>

       <tx:annotation-driven/>

       <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
           <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
       </bean>

   </beans>
   ```
6. And finally the `pom.xml` file:

   ```
   <project        
     xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
       http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
     <groupId>ProvaHibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>ProvaHibernate</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <properties>
         <hibernate.version>5.2.12.Final</hibernate.version>
         <spring.version>4.3.12.RELEASE</spring.version>
     </properties>
     <build>
       <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
       <plugins>
         <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.7.0</version>
           <configuration>
             <source>1.8</source>
             <target>1.8</target>
           </configuration>
         </plugin>
       </plugins>
     </build>
     <dependencies>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
             <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
             <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
             <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
             <version>5.3.4.Final</version>
         </dependency>
           <dependency>
                   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                   <version>5.1.45</version>
           </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
             <version>${spring.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
             <version>${spring.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
             <version>${spring.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
             <version>${spring.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
             <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
             <version>2.1.1</version>
         </dependency>
      </dependencies>
   </project>
   ```

When executed the console shows:

```
    Hibernate: insert into Person (age, name) values (?, ?)
    Hibernate: insert into Person (age, name) values (?, ?)
    Dec 13, 2017 6:26:47 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
    WARN: SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
    Dec 13, 2017 6:26:47 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
    ERROR: Duplicate entry 'Joe' for key 'person_un'
    Exception in thread "main"
    org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    ...
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
    Duplicate entry 'Joe' for key 'person_un'
    ...
```

If I remove the `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().clear();`statement in `HibernateTestDaoImpl.java` letting the Person object in he session then the console shows:

```
    Hibernate: insert into Person (age, name) values (?, ?)
    Hibernate: update Person set age=?, name=? where id=?
```

The [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-detach-reattach) states that `saveOrUpdate` reattaches a detached object to the session:

Is this an Hibernate 5.2 bug of I am missing something.

Comment: What happens when you call merge instead of saveOrUpdate? I'm just curious if this results in the same problem.

Comment: Merge works correctly in both cases, attached or detached. The problem is that merge does not work with transients objects as saveOrUpdate does

Comment: For me this looks like a bug. You should file an issue at https://hibernate.atlassian.net/

Answer (score 0):

It is not a Hibernate bug.

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39926232/1907872) I added a sentence to method `integrate` of `JpaAnnotationsIntegrator` that provoked the problem. The added sentence was:

```
eventListenerRegistry.prependListeners(EventType.SAVE_UPDATE, new JpaSaveEventListener(callbackRegistry));
```

**UPDATE**: I forgot to say that I am not using any listener, just installing the service. I cannot understand why this induce that behavior in `saveOrUpdate`. If I change `prependListeners` by `appendListeners` things go normally.