# Spring Boot 2.1 missing multiple org.hibernate.jpa.event classes

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, integrator

I just tried upgrading one of my projects from Spring Boot 2.0.6 to 2.1 and I now have some missing packages in my JPA annotations integrator class, namely those :

```
import org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPostDeleteEventListener;
import org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPostInsertEventListener;
import org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPostLoadEventListener;
import org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPostUpdateEventListener;
import org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackBuilderLegacyImpl;
import org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackRegistryImpl;
import org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.jpa.CallbackBuilder;
import org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.jpa.ListenerFactory;
import org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.jpa.ListenerFactoryBuilder;
```

Are those no longer available or do they just need to be pulled from a separate dependency now?

***EDIT***

Looks like the entity manager module was merged into the core module of Hibernate but these classes no longer exist (I do use that dependency and SOME of the event package structure is still there).  I think i might have no choice to remain on 2.0.6 ...

By the way, Val Blant's solution on this post is the class in question :

[Hibernate @PostLoad never gets invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802676/hibernate-postload-never-gets-invoked)

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if it is a good idea to use classes from third party `internal` packages.

Comment: I was thinking perhaps the Spring project dropped this specific hibernate dependency / package but it could be pulled again by just adding the package in question to the POM.xml file.  All this class does is allow me to use annotations like PostLoad in my entities to calculate some transient values when loading the entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, through trial and error i found that the last hibernate-entitymanager package that still contained these classes was this one :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.16.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

I added it to my POM.xml file and everything works while using Spring-Boot 2.1.  I just hope this won't have any negative effects on anything else but so far all seems to work great.